# Can the sequence $2+4+6+8+10+\cdots+2n$ at some point be equal to a perfect square?

Tags: sequences-and-series, square-numbers

It's a question I've been asking myself for a long time, without finding the answer.
There are also variants, such as the sequence $2+6+8+10+12+14+\cdots$ which is in fact the same, but without the term $4$, as in the sequence $2+8+10+12+14+\cdots$

If anyone has the answer, I'm interested, thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to express the $n$-th term of the sequence?

Comment: You need to solve $k (k+1)=n^2$ with $n$ the integer solution and $k$ the $k$th partial sum

Comment: Something obvious but useful: there aren't any perfect squares between two adjacent perfect squares. 

Comment: As @youthdoo wrote $n(n+1)=m^2$ by contradiction.
Note that $n^2<n(n+1)<(n+1)^2$. It follows that it is a contradiction

Comment: @youthdoo Your argument solves the problem at once! Much shorter than my solution.

Answer (score 4):

No, that sum is never a perfect square.

Arguing by contradiction, suppose there exist positive integers $m,n$ such that

$$2+4+...+2n = m^2.$$

Recall that

$$2+4+...+2n = 2(1+2+...+n)=2\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)=n(n+1),$$

so the equality becomes

$$n(n+1) = m^2.$$

Note that $n$ and $n+1$ are consecutive integers, so in particular they're coprime. This forces both $n$ and $n+1$ to be perfect squares. That is, there exist positive integers $k,l$ such that $n=k^2$ and $n+1=l^2$. It follows that

$$k^2 +1 = l^2,$$

i.e. $$(l+k)(l-k) = l^2-k^2 = 1.$$

Since the only positive integer which divides 1 is also 1, we conclude that $l+k = l-k = 1$. Thus, $k=0$ and $l=1$, against both $k$ and $l$ being positive.

Comment: You beat me to the general approach. I would have concluded with $n^2<n^2+n<n^2+2n+1$. That is, $n^2+n$ lies between two consecutive integer squares, hence cannot be the square of an integer.

Comment: @KeithBackman Yes, that's also mentioned in the comments above, but I didn't realise when I posted the answer. It solves the problem at once and therefore that's the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen Since $n$ and $n+1$ are coprime, their prime factorisations don't have common primes. Now, $n(n+1)$ is a perfect square, so the exponents of its factorisation are all even. This forces the exponents of the factorisations of both $n$ and $n+1$ to be even; i.e. they're squares.

Comment: It is not good to support PSQ - questions (no effort , no context) and to encourage this user and other users to use this as a do-my-homework-machine.

Comment: @Peter I think the OP had a honest question but simply didn't know how to solve it.